# Insufficient privileges to complete the operation Graph API Azure AD B2C

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to reset Azure b2c users password using nodeJs backend API function using Graph API.

I am using below code to get Access token

```
const url = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${AZURE_TANENT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token`;
        const data = `grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=${AZURE_CLIENT_ID}&client_secret=${AZURE_CLIENT_SECERET}&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`;
```

Once I get the token I am sending Patch request to reset password like below:

```
const url = `${constants.GRAPH_URL}${AZURE_TANENT_ID}/users/${azUserId}`;
    const updatedObj = {
        passwordProfile: {
            password: <newpassword>,
            forceChangePasswordNextSignIn: false,
        }
    };
    try {
        const response = await axios.patch(url, updatedObj, {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        });
        return response.data;
```

I have set Directory.ReadWrite.All and User.ReadWrite.All application permission to Graph API in Azure and set "User Administration" to my B2C App of which clientId and Secrets are used to get token.
[Roles Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSKdP.png)

exact error I am getting:

```
Error creating user: {
  error: {
    code: 'Authorization_RequestDenied',
    message: 'Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.',
    innerError: {
      date: '2023-12-01T06:30:15',
      'request-id': 'someId',
      'client-request-id': 'someId'
    }
  }
}
```

I tried updating the displayName using below code and it works fine:

```
const updatedObj = {
        displayName: "Name Joe"
    };
```

I need solution to update passwordProfile object so that I can reset the password using graph API from backend

Comment: probably need a higher permission Directory.ReadWrite.All. Also check if your app has the correct role to perform sensitive action: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/users?view=graph-rest-1.0#who-can-perform-sensitive-actions

Comment: Already have Directory.ReadWrite.All access still same error

Comment: Normally, as per the docs, for the application to update user account passwords, you'll need to grant the user administrator role to the application. But looks like you've done that?

Comment: Yes I have already added User Administrator to my app following the docs

Answer (score 0):

> In app-only scenarios, the app must be assigned with  **higher privileged**  administrator role to update [**sensitive property**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/users?view=graph-rest-beta#who-can-perform-sensitive-actions) like  `passwordProfile`.

I registered one Azure AD application and added same **API permissions** as below:

[image]

Now, I assigned **User Administrator** role to the application like this:

[image]

In my case, I used Postman to generate **access token** using client credentials flow with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: appId
client_secret: secret 
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used this token in calling `PATCH` request to reset password of user having *Global Administrator* role, I too got **same error** as below:

```http
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}
Content-type: application/json

{
  "passwordProfile": {
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": false,
    "password": "xxxxxxxxxx"
  }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

> The error occurred as *User Administrator* role is **not enough** for resetting password of users having higher privileged roles like *Global Admin* role.

To **resolve** the error, you need to assign the application **higher privileged** role like *Global Administrator* or *Privileged Auth Admin* that can reset passwords of any admin user:

[image]

Now, I generated the token again to run PATCH request and got **response** successfully like this:

```http
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}
Content-type: application/json

{
  "passwordProfile": {
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": false,
    "password": "xxxxxxxxxx"
  }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]